# Xfce panel does't hide when running application in fullscreen mode with dual monitor

Tags: xfce, panel

I'm using the Xfce desktop with dual monitors. When running two applications in fullscreen mode in each monitor, only the Xfce panel of the active monitor is hidden, the panel in the other monitor always shows.

Is there any way to hide the panel of both the two monitors in the fullscreen mode?

Thank you for spending your time to look at my question.

Comment: Any solution has been found yet? I've got the exact same issue.